# How to sort a numpy array based on the values in a specific row?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I was wondering how I would be able to sort a whole array by the values in one of its columns.

I have :

```
array([5,2,8,2,4])
```

and:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

I want to append the first array to the second one like this:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [5,  2,  8,  2,  4]])
```

And then sort the array by the appended row to get either this:

```
array([[1,  3,  4,  0,  2],
       [6,  8,  9,  5,  7],
       [11, 13, 14, 10, 12],
       [16, 18, 19, 15, 17],
       [21, 23, 24, 20, 22],
       [2,  2,  4,  5,  8]])
```

or this:

```
array([[ 2,  1,  3,  4,  0],
       [ 7,  6,  8,  9,  5],
       [12, 11, 13, 14, 10],
       [17, 16, 18, 19, 15],
       [22, 21, 23, 24, 20],
       [ 8,  5,  4,  2,  2]])
```

And then remove the appended column to get:

```
array([[1,  3,  4,  0,  2],
       [6,  8,  9,  5,  7],
       [11, 13, 14, 10, 12],
       [16, 18, 19, 15, 17],
       [21, 23, 24, 20, 22]])
```

or:

```
array([[ 2,  1,  3,  4,  0],
       [ 7,  6,  8,  9,  5],
       [12, 11, 13, 14, 10],
       [17, 16, 18, 19, 15],
       [22, 21, 23, 24, 20]])
```

Is there a code to carry out this procedure. I am very new to python. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [numpy.argsort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to get a list with the sorted indices of your array. Using that you can then rearrange the columns of the matrix.

```
import numpy as np

c = np.array([5,2,8,2,4])    
a = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
              [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
              [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
              [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
              [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])

i = np.argsort(c)
a = a[:,i]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like magic! Would you happen to know how it works as I can't seem to figure it out from the code and documentation? Thanks!

Comment: `argsort` returns an array of indices that would sort the array. The first element in `i` is the position in `c` with the lowest value, etc. You can use lists to index numpy arrays, so `c[i]` would give you the sorted version of `c`. Extending that to 2D arrays, you can use the list to select a bunch of rows or (in this case) columns. You want the columns in the order specified by `i` but you want all the rows untouched, hence `:` (that's a slice that covers all the rows). You should find a tutorial about slicing and indexing in numpy because it's really essential stuff.

Comment: I tried to achieve the same with `a = np.take_along_axis(a, i, axis = 0)` but this gives `ValueError: indices and arr must have the same number of dimensions`. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need numpy to do this; (although if you are using numpy, you can just use the `.transpose()` method of the array class.

What this essentially does, is transpose your array so that it's `array[column][row]`, and then takes each columns, and pairs them with the sortKeys you provided in a list of tuples (the `zip(sortKeys, a)` bit). Then it sorts this list of tuples. By default, sort with sort tuples based on their first value, then their second value, then third, etc. Now you have the columns in order.

then `aNew = [...]` just extracts the columns and creates your new array, still in the `array[column][row]` format, and then transposes it again.

```
a = [[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
     [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
     [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
     [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
     [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]

#transpose a
a = zip(*a)

sortKeys = [5,2,8,2,4]

b = zip(sortKeys, a)

aNew = [row[1] for row in sorted(b)]

#transpose a back
aNew = zip(*aNew)

print aNew
```