# How to sort first row in numpy array and have that sort the second row?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I have an array that looks like this:

```
array = numpy.array([[3,5,4,2,1,6,8],[23,44,52,1,23,22,58]])
```

How do I sort the first row and have it change the result of the second row as well? This is what I mean:

```
new_array = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,8],[23,1,23,52,44,22,58]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a numpy array based on the values in a specific row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331551/how-to-sort-a-numpy-array-based-on-the-values-in-a-specific-row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `argsort`, `array[0].argsort()` gives the indices that will sort the first row and then use the indices to reorder all columns:

```
array[:, array[0].argsort()]
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  8],
       [23,  1, 23, 52, 44, 22, 58]])
```